# Is it bad practice to cache username and password on the client?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Say I created an AngularJS web app that linked with an ASP.NET API. Would it be acceptable to ask the user for their username and password, store it in a cache (client-side) and then use it to make api calls throughout the users session?

When they logged out , the cache would be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

That's probably the worst practice you could do. You should never save password anywhere, not even in your DB. (you store hash in db, but that's separate topic)

One of the usual scenarios is that upon user types in his username/password, your (or authentication) server generates access token (these days Json Web Token) which you store somewhere locally.
Combining access tokens short lifetime with some kind of refresh token is what you're looking for.

All things saved on javascript side are potentialy vulnerable to XSS and other types of attacks.

Answer (score 1):

No it is never a good practice. What you should do is save the session or a access token in browser and use that instead

Answer (score 0):

It is really not a good practice to store username and password in the client cache (by the way, what cache are you using?). The reason being that JavaScript is easier to hack through, and you cannot fully control client's browser at any cost.

You may instead want to go through something called [JSON Web Tokens (JWT)](https://jwt.io/).

These expose secure way to store user's credentials (beware of storing confidential details, such as passwords) on client side, and can be used easily for API calls. There are ready to use SDKs available in your choice of language; refer to the link above.